# Group points based on proximity and equity using QGIS

Tags: point, grouping

I would like to group students based on the nearest school, but also having mixed social categories within the group of students.
I have x,y coordinates for the students and the shcool.

Each student has a field : 'social value' (1,2,3,4,5), based on the parents income. I need to group students not only based on the closest school, but also have a social mix within a group. And the 'social mix' means would have to be as close as possible for all the groups. This would probably mean that I have to iterate through all the possible solutions ? I would need to optimize the groups so that the social mix value is optimized. Ideally the output I would need is a table with all the possibilities (there are 7 schools, so 7 groups, with an equal number of students per school).
[image]